# How to remove an element if its text doesn't match other element text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` and some results, if any of the results doesn't match its text title with the exact `.val()` of the input, its `.parent().parent()` should be removed. The issue I am having is targetting the wrong `this` as I am doing `$this.parent().parent().hide();` but `$this` is `var $this = jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase();`

```
function fetch(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', exactwords:  jQuery('#usp-title').val() },
    success: function(data) {
      var text2;
      var text2B;
      text2 = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
      text2B = text2.toLowerCase();
      jQuery("#datafetch").html(data).promise().done(function(){
        jQuery("#datafetch ul li h2 a").each(function() {
          var $this = jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase();
          if ($this != text2B) {
            $this.parent().parent().hide();
          } else if (text1B == text2B) {
            jQuery("#componi").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `$this` to a string, not to the jQuery node, so when you say `$this.parent().parent()` it won't work. Set `$this = jQuery(this);` instead and perform the value lookup inline in the conditional

```
function fetch(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', exactwords:  jQuery('#usp-title').val() },
    success: function(data) {
      var text2;
      var text2B;
      text2 = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
      text2B = text2.toLowerCase();
      jQuery("#datafetch").html(data).promise().done(function(){
        jQuery("#datafetch ul li h2 a").each(function() {
          var $this = jQuery(this);
          if ($this.text().toLowerCase() !== text2B) {
            $this.parent().parent().hide();
          } else if (text1B == text2B) {
            jQuery("#componi").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: actually we met before on here, nice name ;-)

Comment: Cheers, glad it worked! Yes we have - nice name indeed :-P

Answer (score 0):

Just do `$(this).parent().parent().hide();`

It is bad practice to set `$this` to anything else than `$(this)`.

Just rename your variable and do something like

```
function() {
  var $this = jQuery(this),
      text = $this.text().toLowerCase();
  if (text != text2B) {
    $this.parent().parent().hide();
  } else if (text1B == text2B) {
    jQuery("#componi").attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
  }
}
```